# Name of space cartoon with soda can slime monster

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was some old cartoon, might have been a short, but they were in space and possibly stranded on a ship or exploring a ship. There was a boy and I think his dad, there may have been someone else too. I remember the kid buying or finding a can of soda, there some was sort of pink slime monster in it. It  stuck to the kids face like some sort of Alien facehugger, I think later it took control of the kid's body or turned him into some humanoid slime thing? I think they were trying to find a way to separate them.

This was a long time ago, maybe like 17 years, so I'm not too confidant in how accurate any of this is.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't green with pink text? In that case it sounds like slurm from Futurama: http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Slurm

Comment: @bjorn Nothing about this sounds like Slurm other than "soda can". Slurm is actually green, and it never attacks someone's face out of the can.

Comment: @WakeDemon3 I remember Fry getting attacked by the Slurm queen (slime monster) at the Slurm factory, being squirted in his face and then losing control over himself. Sure, not exactly what OP wrote, but in 17 years, one's memory can change a lot. Also, my recollection of Futurama is for sure not perfect either, far from it, so I thought I could pitch it as a comment and see if it rings a bell for him.

Comment: Definitely was not Futurama.